# Curl is not receiving all data

Tags: php, curl

I'm creating a page to get my clan name.  Now I made a little script to receive the div where my clan name is in. There are 4 `<li></li>` in it but there are only three being received.

This is what it should receive:

> Clan: Heroes of Heaven
>
> Level: 2433
>
> Rank: 20,120
>
> Total XP: 328,197,006

But it receives this:

> Level: 2433
>
> Rank: 20,120
>
> Total XP: 328,197,006

You can see it is not receiving the Clan. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

The following code is being used:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://services.runescape.com/m=adventurers-log/a=134/display_player_profile.ws?searchName=30');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<ul id="generalInfo" data-playername="30">(.*?)<\/ul>/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
else
    print "Not found";
?>
```

---

The following is what I'm trying to get

```
    <ul id="generalInfo" data-playername="30"><li><h5>Clan:</h5> <a href="http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-home/a=134/clan/Heroes of Heaven"><strong>Heroes of Heaven</strong></a></li>
<li><h5>Level:</h5> <strong class="stat level">2433</strong></li>
<li><h5>Rank:</h5> <strong>20,120</strong></li>
<li><h5>Total XP:</h5> <strong>328,197,006</strong></li>
</ul>
```

And this is being recieved

```
<ul id="generalInfo" data-playername="30">
<li><h5>Level:</h5> <strong class="stat level">2433</strong></li>
<li><h5>Rank:</h5> <strong>20,119</strong></li>
<li><h5>Total XP:</h5> <strong>328,197,006</strong></li>
</ul>
```

edit2

```
$regex = '/<a href"(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/s';
```

Line I want :

> **NL BE for fun**

```
$regex = '/<strong>(.*?)<\/strong>/s';
```

Line I want:

```
<strong>NL BE for fun</strong>
```

Comment: can you edit your question to include the output of `var_dump($page)`?

Comment: @andrewsi thats not being used in my script?

Comment: @Kev30 He's asking that you include it so that he can see what is in the `$page` variable after `curl_exec($curl);` executes.

Comment: You'll have to edit it in, yes - it should be added just before the line that starts `$regex`. It will show exactly the data you're being sent.

Comment: @crush done it i'm getting the full page without images and string(58968) "
on the top of the page

Comment: @Kev30 - can you cut and paste the relevant part into your question, please? We don't need to see all of it, just the part you're trying to parse.

Comment: @andrewsi Sorry but i dont really understand u. its just that its only showing me 3 of the 4 code's (it's not showing the clan line)

Comment: @Kev30 - yes. But I want to see the HTML that you're trying to parse. The var_dump shows the output of the page, and I'd like to see the original HTML that you're getting for the list.

Comment: @andrewsi i have added it to the main post. I hope that is what u mean?

Comment: @Kev30 - it is indeed - thank you! Now - is "Heroes of Heaven" included anywhere in the output for `$page`? It looks like your regex is parsing the data correctly, but the data you're looking for isn't included there. If the clan name is not in the page, then there's a problem with the site you're getting the data from, and your code won't be able to fix it.

Comment: @andrewsi The clan name is 100% in the page. Maybe because it's in a url? (<a href><strong>clan name)

Comment: @Kev30 - you're going to have to search for it separately, in that case. You can copy your existing regex to look for the clan name. You can't do it all in one search.

Comment: @andrewsi just like $regex = '/<a href>(.*?)<\/a>/s';?

Comment: @Kev30 - that will match every link on the page. If there's only the one, then yes, it should work. If not, you'll need something more specific - is there a `class` or `id` attribute set you could use, like you're already using `id="generalInfo"`?

Comment: @andrewsi Its only in a <strong>? i only need the clan name

Comment: @Kev30 - then try it and see :D

Comment: @andrewsi tested it getting a "not found"

Comment: @Kev30 - you're going to have to post both the line you're trying to parse and your regex.

Comment: @andrewsi done added it to the begin post (changed clan name old clan quited the game)

Comment: There's a typo in `a href"` - it should be `a href="`

Comment: @andrewsi done it now it's showing me the game logo -.-'

Comment: @Kev30 - like I said, it's picking up all the links that match, rather than just the one you're looking for. As a quick fix, count how many other links are before the clan name, and use that as the parameter for `$list` - ie, if there are two links before the clan name, then you'll want `$list[2];`

Comment: @andrewsi now it's showing nothing like there are no links

Comment: @Kev30 - what isn't showing anything? What code did you try?

Comment: @andrewsi   $regex2 = '<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/s'; and it showing "nothing found" so no results

Comment: @Kev30 What did you update from when you were getting the logo?

Comment: @andrewsi the same, with 1 regex i get logo with 2 (regex and regex2) i get nothing

Comment: @Kev30 - you'll have to edit your code into your question.

Comment: @andrewsi btw ive edited the code and now i'm recieving all urls on the page, this is with clan url:http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-home/a=134/clan/'+response[0].clan+'